# Omit Default Value ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

We are looking at converting our currently in development WCF REST API to use the new ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API because it simplifies a number of things.  One thing I like about WCF is the ability to add a [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue=false)] attribute to data contracts so that certain values that aren't set, will not be serialized back on JSON/XML objects.

Is there an equivalent to this function in the new ASP.NET MVC 4 Web API?  I can't seem to find anything regarding this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the serialization mechanism ASP.NET Web API will use a different serializer. Currently in the beta for JSON it will use a [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) and for XML it uses [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx). But there's a [`UseDataContractSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formatting.xmlmediatypeformatter.usedatacontractserializer%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) property on the [XmlMediaTypeFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formatting.xmlmediatypeformatter%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) which allows you to use the same XML serializer as in WCF (DataContractFormatter).

I don't think that there is an unique way by just decorating your model with some attribute to make those 2 serializer behave the same way unless writing some custom media type formatter. So one possibility is to write custom formatters for XML/JSON and swap the serializer being used to those used in WCF.

Here's [an example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/02/18/using-json-net-with-asp-net-web-api.aspx) of such formatter which uses JSON.Net for JSON. You could adapt it so that it uses [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx) which will take into account the `EmitDefaultValue` property.

Comment: We ended up using the JSON.Net serializer in a custom formatter that gets loaded in the config on app startup as you suggested.  We then just decorate the properties with a DefaultValueAttribute and tell the serializer config to ignore default values.

Answer (score 1):

How to do it in MVC4 released.  Very easy.

http://macroface.wordpress.com/2013/02/28/removing-default-values-in-json-with-the-mvc4-web-api/